# UWP POST ListItems but only some items

Tags: c#, json, rest, post, microsoft-graph-api

OK.  I've figured out how to GET ListItems from my SharePoint List thanks to a little help from here.  Now I am trying to POST a new ListItem.  What I have used so far has only posted a blank ListItem.  So something happened, but there is no data there.

So with the GET I used the following code block:

```
    public async Task<string> GetHttpSPContentWithToken(string url, string token, string listitem)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
           response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharePointListItems.RootObject>(content);
            if (listitem == "Title")
            {
                return result.fields.Title;
            }
            else if (listitem == "UserName")
            {
                return result.fields.UserName;
            }
            else if (listitem == "UserAge")
            {
                return result.fields.UserAge;
            }
            else
            {
                return result.fields.UserTitle;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

With this Class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

public class SharePointListItems
{
    public class UserCreated
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatedBy
    {
        public UserCreated user { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserModified
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastModifiedBy
    {
        public UserModified user { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentReference
    {
    }

    public class ContentType
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
        public string ODataETag { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserAge { get; set; }
        public string UserTitle { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created  { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string AuthorLookupId { get; set; }
        public string EditorLookupId { get; set; }
        public string _UIVersionString { get; set; }
        public bool Attachments { get; set; }
        public string Edit { get; set; }
        public string LinkTitleNoMenu { get; set; }
        public string LinkTitle { get; set; }
        public int ItemChildCount { get; set; }
        public int FolderChildCount { get; set; }
        public string _ComplianceFlags { get; set; }
        public string _ComplianceTag { get; set; }
        public string _ComplianceTagWrittenTime { get; set; }
        public string _ComplianceTagUserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
        public string ODataContext { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
        public string ODataETag { get; set; }

        public DateTime createdDateTime { get; set; }
        public string eTag { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string webUrl { get; set; }
        public CreatedBy createdBy { get; set; }
        public LastModifiedBy lastModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public ParentReference parentReference { get; set; }
        public ContentType contentType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fields@odata.context")]
        public string FieldsODataContext { get; set; }

        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So that makes sense to me, at least so I thought anyway.

But now I am trying to add to the list with this code, but as I said before, I just get a blank row below the previous rows.

```
    public async Task<string> PostHttpSPContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "Title", TitleText.Text },
               { "UserName", UserNameText.Text },
               { "UserAge", UserAgeText.Text },
               { "UserTitle", UserTitleText.Text }
            };
            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I am assuming since I had to you result.fields.somevalue to get to the appropriate value in my code for the GET I need to do something similar for my POST.

Any help would be appreciated.

As I dig further into this, the content that I am trying to put into SharePoint is:

```
"{\"Title\":\"4\",\"UserName\":\"JD\",\"UserAge\":\"28\",\"UserTitle\":\"Visitor\"}"
```

I believe what I need is this:

```
"{\"fields\":{\"Title\":\"4\",\"UserName\":\"JD\",\"UserAge\":\"28\",\"UserTitle\":\"Visitor\"}}"
```

Or something to that affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally.  Here is the changed code:

```
    public async Task<string> PostHttpSPContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var root = new
            {
                fields = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                   { "Title", TitleText.Text },
                   { "UserName", UserNameText.Text },
                   { "UserAge", UserAgeText.Text },
                   { "UserTitle", UserTitleText.Text }
                }
            };

            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

So I had the right idea, just had to figure out how to go about it.